# Como usar Html.BeginForm com JavaScript/Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho uma View para gerar Relatório em meu sistema e estou usando um BeginForm. A ideia é quando dou o submit a minha GridRelatório que é uma outra View, carregue dentro de uma  que tenho dentro na ViewRelatório. Quero fazer com Ajax, porém não estou conseguindo.

**ViewRelatorio**

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Relatorio", "Apontamento", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form"}))
                    { 
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.Label("Período")
                        <div>
                            <input class="datefield"
                                   id="DataInicio" name="DataInicio" type="date" value="1/11/1989" />
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DataInicio, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            <input class="datefield"
                                   id="Datatermino" name="DataTermino" type="date" value="1/11/1989" />
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DataTermino, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group input-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Nome Usuário" />
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    }


<div id="BuscarRelatorio"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para conseguir isso use o evento `submit()` do Jquery.

```
$('#IdParaOSeuForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //evita o evento default do submit

    $.post(
        '@Url.Action("Relatorio", "Apontamento")',
        data: $(this).serialize(),   
        success: function(data){
           $('#BuscarRelatorio').html(data);
        }
    );          
});
```

A linha `$(this).serialize()` retorna uma string concatenada dos names dos seus inputs e seus valores.

Em sua Action retorne uma `PartialView` ou `View`

Doc submit jquery: https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: Valeu @FernandoMedeiros, fiz algumas alterações no script mas funcionou certinho. Obrigado